# I am getting warning "W Unable to open libbeluga.so: dlopen failed: library "libbeluga.so" not found." on xiaomi device

Tags: android, android-ndk

I would like to know if this is something to solve or not. When I searched guthub I found that multiple projects had this in their logs in some bug reports but none was dealing with it as an issue. I also have seen some report about adding missing anroid system files on some repos..